Using visual selections in Luasnip snippets?
For instance, I want to visually select text, and use a hotkey to trigger a snippet which surrounds the section with a markdown code block with my cursor at the end of the first line to write the language name. I looked through the documentation and all I found was $TM_SELECTED_TEXT but I couldn't get it working.
local mdCodeBlock =  s({trig = "````", name = "Codeblock"}, fmt([[
    ````{}
        $TM_SELECTED_TEXT
    ````
    ]], {
      i(1)
  }))


Use the plugn's issue tracker.

The documentation takes some getting used to, for sure. I wrote a guide for putting together different luasnippets here; I in turn learned how to work with visual selections and dynamic nodes here. Hope that helps!

Welcome to Vim! Thanks for your contribution. It would be nice if you could illustrate it with some code.

This answer is not self-contained because of the external links: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible." (From how to answer.)
